# Error: Cannot find buffer gate in the library

Tags: yosys

While attempting to synthesize with Yosys, I am unable to map the logic circuit using only AND, XOR, NOT, and MUX's. This is because I get an error whenever my liberty file excludes BUFX2:
Error:

```
ABC: ** cmd error: aborting 'source <abc-temp-dir>/abc.script'
ABC: Error: Cannot find buffer gate in the library.
ABC: Error: Abc_CommandAbc9Nf(): Mapping into LUTs has failed.
ERROR: Can't open ABC output file `/tmp/yosys-abc-L2LNHN/output.blif'.
```

BUFX2 in liberty file:

```
cell (BUFX2) {
  cell_footprint : buf;
  area : 25;
  cell_leakage_power : 0.0660639;
  pin(A)  {
    direction : input;
    capacitance : 0.00933171;
    rise_capacitance : 0.00930577;
    fall_capacitance : 0.00933171;
  }
  pin(Y)  {
    direction : output;
    capacitance : 0;
    rise_capacitance : 0;
    fall_capacitance : 0;
    max_capacitance : 0.975984;
    function : "A";
    timing() {
      related_pin : "A";
      timing_sense : positive_unate;
      cell_rise(delay_template_5x5) {
        index_1 ("0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.15, 0.3");
        index_2 ("0.06, 0.18, 0.42, 0.6, 1.2");
        values ( \
          "0.080192, 0.099332, 0.125551, 0.141601, 0.160879", \
          "0.09527, 0.119121, 0.146424, 0.159624, 0.180791", \
          "0.119549, 0.142384, 0.170285, 0.182826, 0.208459", \
          "0.206725, 0.226318, 0.258778, 0.269216, 0.29682", \
          "0.336459, 0.356012, 0.387945, 0.399852, 0.425204");
      }
      cell_fall(delay_template_5x5) {
        index_1 ("0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.15, 0.3");
        index_2 ("0.06, 0.18, 0.42, 0.6, 1.2");
        values ( \
          "0.089994, 0.120328, 0.164981, 0.192952, 0.273426", \
          "0.105036, 0.137433, 0.18812, 0.215291, 0.293841", \
          "0.126393, 0.161711, 0.209388, 0.240117, 0.319216", \
          "0.207389, 0.241744, 0.292741, 0.321104, 0.405447", \
          "0.326255, 0.363651, 0.411543, 0.440746, 0.523808");
      }
      fall_transition(delay_template_5x5) {
        index_1 ("0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.15, 0.3");
        index_2 ("0.06, 0.18, 0.42, 0.6, 1.2");
        values ( \
          "0.039104, 0.036002, 0.057053, 0.0624, 0.0708", \
          "0.045857, 0.047088, 0.0684, 0.0702, 0.0768", \
          "0.0726, 0.0744, 0.0786, 0.084, 0.0972", \
          "0.165, 0.1656, 0.1668, 0.1692, 0.1764", \
          "0.315, 0.3156, 0.3168, 0.3162, 0.3198");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I only get this error when trying to use the command (in yosys) [Must include to see delay time]

```
abc -liberty asic_cell_yosys_3.lib -constr yosys_timing.constr;
```

Using the constr file above allows me to see critical path timing delays as illustrated by Clifford in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/yosys/comments/2d3p3a/fast_adder_synthesis/) post.

Setting the area of BUFX2 to an extremely large value like 9999999 still makes Yosys include it in the circuit, even when highly un-optimal.

My goal is trying to optimize depth/critical path timing rather than area/total # of gates, but I can not find a way to do that when

1. I can't remove the buffer gate from the liberty file [with the .constr file]
2. All gates which I need to use (AND,XOR,NOT, MUX) require cell_rise, cell_fall, and fall_transition timing constraints which I have included in the file, but do not necessarily know how it works/ effects delay result

To address #2, how should I change the values to reflect XOR gates requiring approximately 0 delay:

```
cell (XOR2X1) {
area : 1;
  cell_leakage_power : 0.161354;
  pin(A)  {
    direction : input;
    capacitance : 0.0296528;
    rise_capacitance : 0.029651;
    fall_capacitance : 0.0296528;
  }
  pin(B)  {
    direction : input;
    capacitance : 0.0342661;
    rise_capacitance : 0.0339918;
    fall_capacitance : 0.0342661;
  }
  pin(Y)  {
    direction : output;
    capacitance : 0;
    rise_capacitance : 0;
    fall_capacitance : 0;
    max_capacitance : 0.484395;
    function : "(A^B)";
    timing() {
      related_pin : "A";
      timing_sense : non_unate;
      cell_rise(delay_template_5x5) {
        index_1 ("0.005, 0.0125, 0.025, 0.075, 0.15");
        index_2 ("0.06, 0.18, 0.42, 0.6, 1.2");
        values ( \
          "0.084668, 0.100252, 0.11425, 0.123569, 0.136197", \
          "0.097915, 0.113723, 0.126398, 0.138879, 0.150616", \
          "0.119426, 0.133803, 0.150727, 0.160469, 0.175347", \
          "0.200291, 0.21109, 0.234434, 0.245604, 0.260628", \
          "0.324762, 0.343132, 0.359931, 0.370218, 0.387403");
      }

      cell_fall(delay_template_5x5) {
        index_1 ("0.005, 0.0125, 0.025, 0.075, 0.15");
        index_2 ("0.06, 0.18, 0.42, 0.6, 1.2");
        values ( \
          "0.080217, 0.104741, 0.14405, 0.166439, 0.230805", \
          "0.089887, 0.114359, 0.158704, 0.181241, 0.244897", \
          "0.104894, 0.129666, 0.174768, 0.197644, 0.261257", \
          "0.164496, 0.19114, 0.235815, 0.259502, 0.326338", \
          "0.254884, 0.281399, 0.324471, 0.350019, 0.419374");
      }
      fall_transition(delay_template_5x5) {
        index_1 ("0.005, 0.0125, 0.025, 0.075, 0.15");
        index_2 ("0.06, 0.18, 0.42, 0.6, 1.2");
        values ( \
          "0.041331, 0.040781, 0.050767, 0.044749, 0.0696", \
          "0.053453, 0.052285, 0.0624, 0.063, 0.0738", \
          "0.0756, 0.069, 0.078, 0.0792, 0.084", \
          "0.1518, 0.1512, 0.1482, 0.1488, 0.1536", \
          "0.273, 0.273, 0.2682, 0.2652, 0.27");
      }
    }
    timing() {
      related_pin : "B";
      timing_sense : non_unate;
      cell_rise(delay_template_5x5) {
        index_1 ("0.005, 0.0125, 0.025, 0.075, 0.15");
        index_2 ("0.06, 0.18, 0.42, 0.6, 1.2");
        values ( \
          "0.095856, 0.109639, 0.124914, 0.132649, 0.149393", \
          "0.112134, 0.122918, 0.138721, 0.14656, 0.164175", \
          "0.132565, 0.144856, 0.161456, 0.170028, 0.185654", \
          "0.217554, 0.231394, 0.246536, 0.255419, 0.27072", \
          "0.343798, 0.357936, 0.373613, 0.388316, 0.398061");
      }

      cell_fall(delay_template_5x5) {
        index_1 ("0.005, 0.0125, 0.025, 0.075, 0.15");
        index_2 ("0.06, 0.18, 0.42, 0.6, 1.2");
        values ( \
          "0.090864, 0.115106, 0.148564, 0.176005, 0.236451", \
          "0.101631, 0.126046, 0.162396, 0.186432, 0.247857", \
          "0.118398, 0.142704, 0.177128, 0.20129, 0.267362", \
          "0.181148, 0.206, 0.241266, 0.265038, 0.330296", \
          "0.273354, 0.298267, 0.333521, 0.3571, 0.42352");
      }
      fall_transition(delay_template_5x5) {
        index_1 ("0.005, 0.0125, 0.025, 0.075, 0.15");
        index_2 ("0.06, 0.18, 0.42, 0.6, 1.2");
        values ( \
          "0.038733, 0.04056, 0.054628, 0.057339, 0.0624", \
          "0.051463, 0.051355, 0.063, 0.0618, 0.0684", \
          "0.0732, 0.0744, 0.0792, 0.0774, 0.0882", \
          "0.1524, 0.1542, 0.1518, 0.1542, 0.1584", \
          "0.2724, 0.2724, 0.2736, 0.2724, 0.2748");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* actually achieve point 1 with some trickery.

Yosys' internal cells start with `$`, e.g. `$_AND_` which you can see if you run `abc` without any other arguments. One of these internal cells is `$_BUF_` which represents a buffer cell. Since to Yosys buffer cells are identical to wires, the `opt` command will replace all instances of `$_BUF_` with simple wires.

This means you can instantiate `$_BUF_` cells by replacing the `BUFX2` cell name with `"$_BUF_"` (the quotes are needed to escape the `$`), keeping ABC happy because there's a cell buffer, and then after running an `opt` pass, the buffers have disappeared from your netlist.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your explanation does make sense. However, I replaced BUFX2 with $_BUF_ , but this caused a syntax error in my .lib file. Do you know why this is?

Comment: I just checked my own Liberty file: you need to use `"$_BUF_"` (note the quotes) as the cell name. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yep, that did it! For reference, replacing it with "$_BUF_" does not include BUF in the area/ total number of gates, and reduces the delay by a very small amount (e.g. for an 8 bit calculation in my module, the difference was only 55.67 ps. Thanks again.